# Concatenate Javascript files in contao

Tags: javascript, concatenation, contao

My website is using many javascript files of which some are loaded from the core. Is there any way to concatenate these js files into a single file? I've seen the usage of '|static'. But it is not wise to add '|static' into core file. 
So is there any way to achieve this in contao itself? I some other cms there is an option for "concatenateJS ". Like that, whether there is an option in contao core? If not, is there any other options for concatenation?

I had referred to https://rocksolidthemes.com/de/contao/blog/contao-ladezeit-optimieren.   But it is not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "But it is not wise to add '|static' into core file"?

Comment: Usually we won't edit the core extensions. Because while upgrade, that changes will be lost..

Comment: Which Contao version are you using?

Comment: Contao 4.3 is the version used.

Comment: You should update to Contao 4.4.8 btw. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Contao 4 you need to enable the **Combine scripts** option in your page layout. This will combine all scripts containing the `|static` flag into one file.

This options is enabled by default in Contao 4.5+

Comment: I need to add a script tag just before the closing of the body tag. I wrote it as $GLOBALS['TL_JS_BODY'][] = '.../../js/script.js|static'; But it is not getting seen before the body tag. Is this is not the right method?

Comment: You can use `TL_JQUERY`, `TL_MOOTOOLS` or `TL_BODY` for that. I think it's preferable to use the latter.